# AJAX inserting a row at any position in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am building a rails app and I use AJAX to populate the newly created entry in the table(in views folder).

$("#table tr:first").after('<%= @record.priority %>')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#career_objective_table tr:nth-child(4)").after('<%= @career_objective.priority %>')
```

Replace 4 with any number